# Connecting to CloudSQL from Kubernetes: cannot validate certificate

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to connect to a CloudSQL database from a container running in Kubernetes (not Google). I can connect using for instance IntelliJ, but Kubernetes refuses to connect

> failed to connect to `host=<ip> user=user database=db`: failed to
> write startup message (x509: cannot validate certificate for 
> because it doesn't contain any IP SANs)

The message is connect in that the information is indeed missing in the certificate generated by Google.

Then how am I supposed to connect?

Comment: Provide more information about how you configured Cloud SQL and the certificate that you are using. The CN for the certificate should match how you are connecting. For example, if the certificate is not configured with an IP address in the common name list then you cannot connect using an IP address (or you will have to disable SSL verification). A good answer requires more details in your question.

Comment: Please check the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on what topics you can ask on StackOverflow. This question doesn't appear to be programming related so this is best asked on DBA StackExchange or Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-cloud-sql-postgres-demo) you can connect to cloud SQL (Postgres) instance using Cloud SQL Proxy container as sidecar container.

Comment: It does seem like a soliution but it also looks like google specific extra steps that in principle should not be required. For instance, I can connect using user/pass+certificates from the command like and IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say for sure because you haven't provided much information - you don't have any examples or information of how you are trying to connect other than "from kubernetes", which makes it hard to diagnose what your specific problem is.

However - I'm going to make a couple of assumptions:

1. Based on the error message, you are using Go
2. Based on a another comment, you are trying to use self-managed SSL certificates instead of the Cloud SQL proxy

If that's the case, you may be running into this issue which requires you to use a custom verify method when using more recent Go versions: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/40748#issuecomment-673612108